# Beginner - Syntax to concatenate a variable within a findViewById and within a string or textview assignment

Tags: java, android, concatenation

I'm new to android programming with very little experience, I'll try ask the correct question but I apologize if some of my understanding isn't quite up to scratch.

I'm building a basic calculator app with buttons 0 to 9.  The user can use these to input that specific number into a text field.

I have the same piece of code (below) to do my button action for all 0 to 9 buttons.  Just where to see the number 1 it's replaced with that buttons relevant number.

```
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_calc_1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String number_1 = ("1");
            TextView  Insert_Number_1 = (TextView ) findViewById(R.id.editTextoutput);
            TextView Insert_Number_1_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CurrentDisplay);
            Insert_Number_1.append(number_1);
            Insert_Number_1_view.append(number_1);

        }
    });
```

So i'm writing a subroutine of the same code that I can then call upon for the relevant button.

```
        public String numberbuttons(String value){
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_calc_1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String number_1 = ("1");
            TextView  Insert_Number_1 = (TextView ) findViewById(R.id.editTextoutput);
            TextView Insert_Number_1_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CurrentDisplay);
            Insert_Number_1.append(number_1);
            Insert_Number_1_view.append(number_1);

        }
    });

}
```

Bear in mind this is a work in progress.

**My question is basically how do I add the variable numberbuttons to the button_calc_(insert numberbuttons here)**

EDIT:

Okay so from the second block of code.  I want to use the numberbuttons variable within the findViewById(R.id.button_calc_1).

So in my head I picture it like this.

```
findViewById(R.id.button_calc_+(numberbuttons);
```

The same for when I call a textview.  I picture it like this.

```
TextView  Insert_Number_+(numberbuttons) = (TextView ) findViewById(R.id.editTextoutput);
```

Comment: You should be more specific what you want to implement. Try to give some example as well.

Comment: Okay i'll update now of what i've been attempting to do.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Why doesn't you use an array?

Comment: @YoavSternberg I will be as my next progression in programming.  I've not used arrays yet.  I'm slowly improving the code of this to learn and arrays was a little further down the list from now.  Thanks

Comment: @TwizzleBizzle this is not things work in android, i think you can't do this plz correct anyone if i am wrong. In your xml give each button a different id and then use that id to get them in your code, this concatenation kind of thiing won't work.

Comment: @jackjay Thank you for the reply.  They currently all have their own ID in the xml and they're each called as a separate almost identical piece of code(barring the specific button identifiers).  I wanted to just call upon each piece of code changing just where it references 1 to whatever button is pressed.

Comment: Ok so I think I understand what you are trying to do, but what you need to understand is that the findViewById() method is not looking for a string with the name of the resource, it's looking for an ID, R.id.xxxx just resolves to an ID.

What you need to do is store each button in an list like an ArrayList and then loop through that array list and do whatever you need to do.

Comment: @TwizzleBizzle unfortunately you can't do this, `findViewById()` takes resource id aas parameter which is int, but when you do such concatanation it becomes string which will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The findViewById() method requires an integer, not a String, so you cannot just pass in a String with the name of the button that you are trying to use. When you use R.id.xxx you are passing a reference to the resource, which is actually just an int.

To accomplish what you want I suggest using a list of some type to store the buttons, and then looping through this. Please see an example below.

```
ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();

buttons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)); //Do this for all the buttons.

for(Button b : buttons){
    b.setText("1"); //Do whatever you need to each button in here.
}
```

If you wanted to use a method to manage all your buttons, you can do this too!

```
changeButton((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1));

private void changeButton(Button b){
    //Change the button
}
```

EDIT:

To be more relevant to your question if I understand correctly, to add an event handler to each.

```
ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();

buttons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)); //Do this for all the buttons.

for(int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++){
    Button b = buttons.get(i);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String number = String.valueOf(i);
        TextView  Insert_Number_1 = (TextView ) findViewById(R.id.editTextoutput);
        TextView Insert_Number_1_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CurrentDisplay);
        Insert_Number_1.append(number_1);
        Insert_Number_1_view.append(number_1);

    }
});
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you for the answer.  Just the way my head works!  I don't see why the reference to the resource can't also have a variable inside.

I'm not sure the bottom code would work as again to find the correct view in the findViewById each button is button1, button2, button3...

Comment: @TwizzleBizzle Yeah, unless you create your layout in the Java code you will always have to reference every ID from the XML. Just the way the last method does it allows you to write the event handler code once instead of 9 times.